# Selecting max of sum of rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table in the database like this:

```
student_id | subject_id  | get_ca1  | get_ca2  | get_exam
----------------------------------------------------------
   101     |     1       | 10       | 7        | 10
   102     |     2       | 5        | 5        | 10
   103     |     1       | 9        | 10       | 4
   101     |     1       | 8        | 10       | 10
   103     |     2       | 2        | 10       | 10
   104     |     1       | 7        | 8        | 5
   101     |     2       | 7        | 8        | 5
```

I want to get the highest score of a student in a subject. But first, I would have to sum up the rows `get_ca1 + get_ca2....+ get_exam` to another column to get the total scores of each student in a particular subject.

Then I want to get the Max score from the total. This means;

the highest score in subject_id = 1 is 28 gotten by student_id=101 
the highest score in subject_id = 2 is 22 by student_id = 103

So far, this is my query:

```
SELECT MAX(`get_ca1`+`get_ca2`+`get_exam`) 
AS max_score 
FROM exam_results WHERE `subject_id`=1
```

This outputs 28.

Now, this is how I want my table in view to look:
For student_id= 103

```
subject | ca1  | ca2  | exam  | highest
----------------------------------------
 Maths  |  9   | 10   | 4     | 28
 Eng    |  2   | 10   | 10    | 22
```

This is where my problem lies. I tried putting the code directly in the view file like this:

```
<td>
<?php 
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(`get_ca1`+`get_ca2`+`get_exam`) 
AS max_score FROM exam_results WHERE `subjects.id`=1");
$highscore = $query->row();
echo $highscore->max_score;
?>
</td>
```

It outputs 28 correctly. However, it shows 28 in all the subjects. I'm guessing is because of this `` WHERE `subjects.id`=1" ``
If I'm to go by this method, how do I get the highest scores to show in each subject column?
is it `` WHERE `subjects.id`=.'"$subject_id"`" ``?

But I would prefer the MVC method which I'm not so familiar with.

so far...

Model

```
 public function GetMaxScore($subject_id) 
    {
$this->db->select_max('`get_ca1`+`get_ca2`+`get_exam` AS max_score');
$this->db->where('subject_id', $subject_id);
return $this->db->get('max_score')->row(); 
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function GetMaxScore($subject_id)
    {
$data = $this->examgroupstudent_model->GetMaxScore($subject_id); 
 return $data->max_score;
    }
```

If this is correct by any means, how do I output it in my view?

Comment: I understand that, alongside the results for a particular student/subject, you want to have the highest total score for any student for that subject.  But are you doing this query for *all* students or just a particular student?

Comment: the query is for all students

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean ```select version();```?